# Xpath: extract a link from the href tag

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I am working on the following webpage and want to go on the each hotel page to scrape data: 
https://www.booking.com/searchresults.de.html?dest_id=204;dest_type=country&

The link to the hotel page is in the href tag.

```
<h3 class="sr-hotel__title-wrap">
  <a class="hotel_name_link url" href=" /hotel/ch/hirschen-za1-4rich.de.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAQoggJCC2NvdW50cnlfMjA0SAdYBGgsiAEBmAEHuAEHyAEN2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAKy29byBcACAQ&dest_id=204&dest_type=country&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=1&hpos=1&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&srepoch=1582673331&srpvid=b5d3a51914210067&ucfs=1&from=searchresults ;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <span class="sr-hotel__name " data-et-click=" "> Hotel Hirschen </span>
    <span class="invisible_spoken"> Wird in neuem Fenster geöffnet </span>
  </a>
</h3>
```

I tried to extract the link to the hotel page with following xpaths but I got nothing.

```
.//*[@class="sr-hotel__title "]/a/@href
//a[@class="hotel_name_link url"]/@href
```

Or should I also use in the xpath the levels above (div)?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: @zx485 ok..., thank you! But this is the link in html code. How can I extract it or is there another way to go on the hotel page?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the link again. Now it is correct.

Comment: Your second expression works for me on the supplied html. The first one has a typo (should be `.//*[@class="sr-hotel__title-wrap"]/a/@href`), but once it's fixed, that works, too.

Comment: The first expression could also be fixed with `//h3[@class[normalize-space(.)='sr-hotel__title']]//@href`

Comment: It doesn't work for me... I use it like that in scrapy response.xpath('//h3[@class[normalize-space(.)="sr-hotel__title"]]//@href') Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second xpath work for me **BUT** only if I set correct `User-Agent` ie.

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
```

Without `User-Agent` or with short version `Mozilla/5.0` it redirects to

```
 https://www.booking.com/searchresults.de.html
```

(without arguments `?dest_id=204;dest_type=country&`) and it get empty page without hotels.

Maybe you should check first what you get from url - ie. save HTML in file and open in browser - maybe you also get empty page or some warning for bots.

---

Minimal working code

You can put it in one file and run as normal script without creating project.

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['https://www.booking.com/searchresults.de.html?dest_id=204;dest_type=country&']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        #items = response.xpath('.//*[@class="sr-hotel__title "]/a/@href').extract()
        items = response.xpath('//a[@class="hotel_name_link url"]/@href').extract()
        for item in items:
            yield {'url': item.strip()}  # to save in CSV


# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Setting correct User Agent worked for me! Now I get right URLs!